# Wi-Fi..Ethernet..Nothing Works for 13.10

Tags: wireless, drivers, 13.10, broadcom, ethernet

I've been at this for a couple of days. Can't find a solution that works.

Did the trial of 13.1 and everything worked great. As soon as I did the install on my laptop (Dell Vostro 1520) I can't get any type of connection whatsoever.

Wi-Fi isn't working because I need to install the Broadcom STA driver. The one on my computer, according to the forums, is broken. I tried bringing it over from another web-capable laptop and fresh installing it but it's (ubuntu) still telling me it can't access the web, and therefore can't install it. I'm sure everyone can see flaw here.

So, I then try to use Ethernet to do this. According to my network connections, I'm connected. According to anything I do to try to actually access the network, I'm not connected to anything.

My computer doesn't acknowledge any available Wi-Fi connections whatsoever. Terminal is seeming pretty useless, as pretty much every route I'm taking it's telling me it can't.

This is beyond frustrating. I've never had this much trouble connecting to a network in my life.

Please help. I'll be happy to answer any questions.

Thanks a Ton

Answer (score 0):

that happen to me.
Just run in terminal

```
uname -a
```

if the kernall is less than 3.11.0.12
then you should update grub

```
sudo update-grub2
```

if you have two systems
then update the grub from other system